# How to mount Docker container volumes

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

My requirement is like this:

**Q) I have a little `python` app running a small `flask` server on a docker container. I need to pass a value to this container that will return from the python server.** but I need to change this passing value occasionally and **I DON'T WANT TO** build the image every time I do a change to this passing value.

For this what I have done this set `.env` file and set the environment variables I need to pass like below:

this is my `.env`:

```
MY_NAME=John McBeth
```

This is my `server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import os

PORT = 8083

return_value = os.environ(['MY_NAME']) # value I am getting from .env

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return str(return_value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT)
```

And I am building this from a `docker-compose.yaml` as below:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  backend: 
    build: ./backends/banuka
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
      MY_NAME: ${MY_NAME} // this is where I am passing the value in `.env`   
    ports: 
      - 8080:8083
```

**PROBLEM :** How can I set a volume to this container, that every time I change this name in `.env` it will reflect right after **without building the image again and running?**

Comment: You can export a variable using `-e`. You don't need to mount a file.

Comment: But still, I have to build the image right?

Comment: environment variables and their values are persisted when container created. Mount a file in docker-compose using volumes and then read this file in your python script rather than taking value from environment variable. So whenever you restart/start your container it will read latest content of the file.

Comment: @fly2matrix this is the solution I was looking for. Can you please provide with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  backend: 
    build: ./backends/banuka
    volumes:
      - .:/path/to/project
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports: 
      - 8080:8083
```

You can set `/path/to/project` to whatever you prefer, this will be the path inside your container, the `.` before only means current directory, which I suppose is the root directory of your project, you can change this too to any path in your machine you'd like to mount.

Also, you can set the `.env` file directly in compose with `env_file` option, which is what I actually recommend

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

Answer (score 0):

Create a file along with docker-compose.yml

`echo "John McBeth" > file_with_env_content`

Mount file in container.

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  backend: 
    build: ./backends/banuka
    volumes:
      - ./file_with_env_content:/opt/file_with_env_content
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"

    ports: 
      - 8080:8083
```

And Change you python script to read content from temp file.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import os

PORT = 8083

#return_value = os.environ(['MY_NAME']) # value I am getting from .env
f = open("/opt/file_with_env_content", "r")
return_value = f.readline() # Write your logic to select any specific line or key value pair etc.
f.close()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return str(return_value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT)
```

Comment: This is working as long as the container is restarted. I have to restart the container everytime I did a change. But I want to reflect it immediately right after the changes are done to that file `file_with_env_content` without really restarting the container.. how can i do this?

Comment: For this, you need to have a listening program (Keep checking file modification timestamp at regular intervals). that will keep checking the content of the file. If something detected then stop the previous execution and start a new one.